# Why does fgets function in the program below (see detail) interprets the length of string by one extra character?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, gets

Here is the source code with gets function:

```
//Finding length of a string//
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    //Finding length by user written code//
    int i=0;
    char ar[200];
    printf("So enter your string here: ");
    gets(ar);
    while(ar[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    printf("The length of your string is: %d",i);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the input and output:

```
So enter your string here: Hello World
The length of your string is: 11
```

But if the gets function is replaced by fgets function, that is if the code is written as:

```
//Finding length of a string//
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    //Finding length by user written code//
    int i=0;
    char ar[200];
    printf("So enter your string here: ");
    fgets(ar,200,stdin);
    while(ar[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    printf("The length of your string is: %d",i);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Then input and output become:

```
So enter your string here: Hello World
The length of your string is: 12
```

So, why is fgets function giving the length by one extra character?

Comment: You might have forgotten about the `'\n'`?

Comment: Strings in C are null-terminated, so what means `"Hello World"` is actually `"Hello World\0"`. Also, use `strlen` to count chars ;)

Comment: You could have tried printing the numeric value of each of its elements to see what it contains... and read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx).

Comment: A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

Comment: You will see the same behavior with both *line-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgets` and `getline`)

Comment: @Shark that is what I have used to find the length of the string. As soon as the the '\0' is read, the while loop is terminated and there is no further increment in i.

Comment: Sourabh Khandelwal, @Weather Vane nicely suggests to to printf the value of each character.  Try  `for (i=0; ar[i]; i++) printf("%d\n", ar[i]);` to discover why the length is 12.  (there is not an extra character - you typed 12 keys and 12 characters were saved.)

Comment: Never use `gets`. It's inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language.

Answer (score 0):

It is because fgets stores a `\n` character before adding the null-terminating `\0`.

from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) fgets

`... Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.`

and from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) gets

`The newline character, if found, is discarded and does not count toward the number of characters written to the buffer.`